# Multiple parallel data rest call in angular

Tags: angularjs, rest, google-chrome, data-transfer

This is more like a question about the right approach:

We have an single page web application in angularjs that is loading a view that contains multiple diagrams. Each diagram fetch the data that needs to be displayed through the REST service. There is a limitation in chrome with 6 connection simultaneously. As we have views with more than 10 diagrams the data fetch results in queuing the calls untils previous one are resolved. This appears to the user as if the data fetch is slow.

- Is there a way to execute all calls in parallel (same server, different REST endpoints)?
- What where the single page solution that would not be limited by the browser but provide faster throughput?

Caching in frontend is only partially applicable, due to the active filtering of data by the user.

Answer (score 0):

One solution will be combining multiple request to one request, by that the overhead of multiple connection establishment time will be gone.

You can make a proxy api which can take care of them.

The problem with combining endpoints is, if any of your endpoint has higher processing time then the other combined endpoints response has to wait for it.

Best solution is, make the endpoints first enough so 6 connections are enough